# How to avoid crashes due to missing string entries?

Tags: android, localization

I have an app translated in 3 languages: English, German, Polish

So I have these three folders for the languages in the project:

```
values
strings.xml

values-en
strings.xml

values-de
strings.xml

values-pl
strings.xml
```

I have realized that If I put all strings into values folder and have some strings missing in the Polish version that the app crashes when accessing the missing strings in the Polish version.

I would have expected that the system just gets the string from the default values folder if it does not find it in values-pl folder.

Is there any way to catch these potential missing string crashes? EVen if I could get a warning in the compiler that the string in any language is missing would be OK?

**EDIT AND ADDITION**

In fact another string was missing in the default too.... so thanks for the answer/comments!

But now I have also tested the case where there is a string simply missing in the default strings.xml file only BUT present in all the other files. I do not get any warning or anything else.

So in this case if ALL the strings are present in de,en,pl but one is missing in default, then the app crashes in China for example (I understand of course because the default is missing).

BUT what bothers me is that I do not find any way to check the completeness of all referenced strings in code. This is how I access the missing string:

```
context.getString(R.string.MYTRING_abc),
```

Comment: From my expiriens if there are missing strings the project doesn't compiles. I'm using eclipse juno.

Comment: If you test your app, in every available languages, you wouldn't have to ask this question. To me it doesn't make sense, why you just don't make sure, that the strings are available before publishing your app. Not all exceptions should be catched, they should be dealt with before they can happen.

Comment: "I have an app translated in 3 languages: English, German, Polish" -- no, you have your app translated in four languages: English, German, Polish, and whatever language is in your `res/values/` directory. If you truly only have your app translated into three languages, then one of those languages needs to move into `res/values/`. You want `res/values/` to have the default value for every string resource, in whatever you wish to consider your default language to be.

Comment: Also, I don't see how the app would crash, if a string is missing in a specific language - could you tell me how to reproduce this?

Comment: I agree. IME, if a string isn't found in one of the localization directories, it's fetched from the default directory. Is it possible that OP is complaining about a build-time error message from Eclipse?

Comment: @Darwind One way to reproduce it is to have string arrays that aren't completely translated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In eclipse menu `Window --> Properties --> Android --> Lint Error Checking` in the `Correctness:Messages` section set `MissingTranslation` to Error in the `Severity` box. When compile in your default values string.xml each untranslated string would be marked. 
Most of the time after build you have to click the `refresh icon` in the `Link Warnings` window (next to `Outline window`) to have these errors shown.
If there is error after fixing them you have to clean your project, otherwise Eclipse won't built and still show these errors.

Answer (score 2):

*I would have expected that the system just gets the string from the default values folder if it does not find it in values-pl folder.*

It works that way for `<string>`s, but not for the elements of `<string-array>`s.  If one of the translations has a `<string-array>` without the correct number of elements, you'll get a crash if the app attempts to access a missing element.  My solution for the past couple years has been to store every string array in a non-translated XML file, referencing translatable strings.

**res/values/misc.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Resources that are neither styles nor strings to be translated. -->
<resources>
  <string-array name="notification_line_content_entries">
    <item>@string/time_remaining</item>
    <item>@string/time_since_status_change</item>
    <item>@string/vital_signs</item>
  </string-array>
</resources>
```

This way if one of the independent strings isn't translated, the array is still valid and you fall back to the default translation for that particular value.

Of course the other possibility is that, as suggested in the comments, you don't have a default translations for every string in `res/values/`.

Comment: thanks, it's just a normal string and it's missing in the values directory, but there is no warning or anything else!

Answer (score 1):

In **Android Studio**:

```
Settings -> Editor -> Inspections -> (search for or find) Incomplete translation
```

Set to `info` or `warning`. `Error` prevents the app from being created when you press `create signed APK`.

In my own experience, I only get this error when I create a build (non-debug through USB debugging, meaning when it is a signed build) but changing the incomplete translation to `warning` (so I get a notification it isn't finished, but it isn't ignored in case I just forgot) (or `info` for that matter) allows the app to be built and it functions just like in debug where incomplete translations go to the default value.

But if you experience the error in debug as well, this should still work and prevent crashing in APK creation